# Convert file path to file url[NSUrl]

Tags: ios, objective-c, filepath, nsurl

I'm try to file upload operation using `AFNetworking` multi-part form data. I'm getting following error. I could find out what is error.

`[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]`
Also used `[[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] filePathURL]`, But doesn't help me.
When I log filepath string: It shows correct path : `/var/mobile/Applications/3CBF5127-B2FF-49C3-AC98-16BD0886EEE7/Documents/20140326105108_slno.ma4`

**Error:**
`@"NSLocalizedFailureReason" : @"Expected URL to be a file URL"`

`Questions:` How to convert this path string to `file url`?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `NSURL`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You want to use this method instead:

```
+ (id)fileURLWithPath:(NSString *)path
```

Answer (score 26):

Try in this way.

```
 NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

    //OR ... Use `

 +[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]
```

OR take a look at [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope it helps you.